# Invoking service with @RequestParam and @RequestBody using postman client

Tags: spring, postman

Was trying to invoke the service 
http://IP:8080/PQRS/LMN/XYZ/runTest/scheduledautomation/1/XYZ

with below JSON String

```
[ {"paramName":"TEST_TARGET_IDENTIFIER","paramValue":"ETest"},{"paramName":"TEST_SOURCE_ENTRY_IDENTIFIER","paramValue":"com.pack.etest"}]
```

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
@RequestMapping(value = "/runTest/scheduledautomation/{runId}/{testEngine}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void runScheduledAutomatedTest(@RequestParam String cronExpresssion,
        @RequestParam(required = false) @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime endTime,
        @PathVariable Integer runId,
        @PathVariable TestEngine testEngine,
        @RequestBody List<TestEngineParam> testEngineParams) throws Exception { //Some Code }
```

Response :

Required String parameter 'cronExpresssion' is not present

how to invoke mixed `@RequestParam` and `@RequestBody` services on postman client ?

Comment: By passing the parameters... You currently aren't passing the parameters, only JSON.

Comment: i.e. you're missing `?cronExpresssion=blabla`at the end of the URL. Note that there are 3 `s`in this parameter name. Using request parameters with POST is bizarre. Why don't you pass this information as part of the JSON body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fear you want a little bit too much: RequestParam, RequestBody AND the whole thing as a REST query. At least two of the three things are mutually exclusive.

I think you could even get Postmaster to do this by modifying the called URL to:

http://IP:8080/PQRS/LMN/XYZ/runTest/scheduledautomation/1/XYZ?cronExpression=your-expression

Of course this would ruin your REST interface, but as I said: your handler method is a little bit *"over-ambitious"*.