# How to send POST-request with request arguments using cURL?

Tags: java, curl, spring-rest

I am trying to send POST-request to my local app using cURL:

```
host="http://localhost:8080"
$(curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"Test", "description":"Test"}' $host/games/new?user_id=c13fb734-c72a-48a0-9fd7-5fbc79c6285a)
```

My controller:

```java
@RequestMapping("games")
@RestController
public class GameController {

    private static final String ROOT_URL = ServerConfig.GAMES_HOST + "/games";

    @PostMapping(value = "new")
    public ResponseEntity<String> add(@RequestParam("user_id") UUID userId,
                      @RequestBody String newGame) {
        String url = ROOT_URL + "/new?userId=" + String.valueOf(userId);
        RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
        return template.postForEntity(url, newGame, String.class);
    }
}
```

But in Spring I'm getting an error:

```
{"errors":["user_id should be of type java.util.UUID"],"status":"BAD_REQUEST","message":"Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.UUID'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid UUID string: new"}
```

I.e. cURL sends `new` as value of `user_id`.
Where can error be?

Comment: What if you include the user_id in the JSON? like `-d '{"name":"Test", "description":"Test", "user_id":"c13fb734-c72a-48a0-9fd7-5fbc79c6285a"}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Analysis

Long story short, conceptually, `@RequestParam` and `@RequestBody` are mutually exclusive: query parameters (`@RequestParam`) are sent as a request body.

Please see the additional details here:

- [How are parameters sent in an HTTP POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551194/how-are-parameters-sent-in-an-http-post-request).
- [Spring MVC - Why not able to use @RequestBody and @RequestParam together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19468572/spring-mvc-why-not-able-to-use-requestbody-and-requestparam-together).
- [spring - Invoking service with @RequestParam and @RequestBody using postman client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30979393/invoking-service-with-requestparam-and-requestbody-using-postman-client).
- [spring - What is difference between @RequestBody and @RequestParam?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28039709/what-is-difference-between-requestbody-and-requestparam).

## Solution

Currently, there are two alternatives:

1. Stick to the request parameters (`@RequestParam`) only: pass every parameter (i.e. every JSON property) as a query parameter.
2. Stick to the request body (`@RequestBody`) only, for example:

   1. Pass everything as a JSON request body.
   2. Pass everything as a JSON request body, except the `user_id` parameter. The parameter may be made `@PathVariable` and the `@RequestMapping` should use the appropriate placeholder to reference it.